# Finding line number from Kernel oops PC

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

If I got a kernel oops, what is 0xac/0x2b8 below means?  Also, how can I get the line number in the file where the function is?   This is linux on ARM arch.

PC is at get_next_timer_interrupt+0xac/0x2b8

Comment: See also the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151538/addr2line-on-kernel-module

Answer (score 4):

The kernel might need various debug options to be enabled, but 'addr2line' should give you file name and line number for an address. http://elinux.org/Addr2line_for_kernel_debugging

Answer (score 3):

It means that exception occured at `get_next_timer_interrupt+0xac` address. `0xac` is the offset in the `get_next_timer_interrupt` procedure. `0x2b8` means how long is the procedure where the exception occurred (`get_next_timer_interrupt`).

You may decode it using `addr2line` as skorgon wrote, or use `objdump` command to disassemble Linux Kernel and find the problematic line in kernel sources. Of course, Linux kernel has to be compiled with debugging symbols.