# Segmentation fault while doing modprobe

Tags: segmentation-fault, kernel, kernel-module

I am inserting a module by doing modprobe. I've inserted the dependent first. And when I do modprobe I get a Segmentation Fault with the following Call Trace.

```
root@ATCA-8310-0-T0:/root> modprobe edac-core
root@ATCA-8310-0-T0:/root> modprobe mpc85xx-edac
Kcore timestamp : 1386018611.306434
Kcore HighResolution timestamp : 23A022A24
Kcore timestamp : 1386018611.306434
Kcore HighResolution timestamp : 23A428F7A
Oops: Kernel access of bad area, sig: 11 [#1]
SMP NR_CPUS=8 P4080 DS
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/block/md0/dev
Modules linked in: sctp binfmt_misc vmc_stub edac_core mpc85xx_edac(+) [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
NIP: f6580048 LR: c0244890 CTR: f658001c
REGS: e9d43be0 TRAP: 0300   Not tainted  (2.6.34.12-kairos-edac-vMC-dec02)
MSR: 00029002 <EE,ME,CE>  CR: 24002428  XER: 00000000
DEAR: 00000000, ESR: 00000000
TASK = e9d1f2f0[1711] 'modprobe' THREAD: e9d42000 CPU: 3
GPR00: c0244890 e9d43cc0 e9d1f2f0 f658240c 00000000 ffffffff 00000000 00000002
GPR08: 529cf733 00000000 eb0bf884 e9d43d18 24002428 1001efe0 00000001 00000000
GPR16: 00000003 00000000 10001bf0 00000000 100170c8 00000000 00000000 eb90ed60
GPR24: c06a692c ffffff01 ffffff02 f657b014 c0244978 00000000 e9d43d18 eb646088
NIP [f6580048] edac_new_smi+0x2c/0x18c [mpc85xx_edac]
LR [c0244890] ipmi_smi_watcher_register+0x140/0x228
Call Trace:
[e9d43d10] [c0244890] ipmi_smi_watcher_register+0x140/0x228
[e9d43d50] [f6581700] mpc85xx_mc_err_probe+0x3d8/0x510 [mpc85xx_edac]
[e9d43db0] [c03e6738] of_platform_device_probe+0x58/0x98
[e9d43dd0] [c0260a5c] driver_probe_device+0xa0/0x188
[e9d43df0] [c0260c00] __driver_attach+0xbc/0xc0
[e9d43e10] [c0260118] bus_for_each_dev+0x70/0xac
[e9d43e40] [c0260888] driver_attach+0x24/0x34
[e9d43e50] [c025f9e0] bus_add_driver+0x1b0/0x278
[e9d43e80] [c0260f70] driver_register+0x94/0x164
[e9d43ea0] [c03e65f0] of_register_driver+0x30/0x70
[e9d43eb0] [f658607c] mpc85xx_mc_init+0x54/0x1490 [mpc85xx_edac]
[e9d43ec0] [c000226c] do_one_initcall+0x3c/0x1f4
[e9d43ef0] [c007c1b4] sys_init_module+0xf8/0x22c
[e9d43f10] [c00109f0] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x4
--- Exception: c01 at 0xff62888
    LR = 0x100035f0
Instruction dump:
4e800020 9421ffb0 7c0802a6 bf61003c 7c9f2378 7c7d1b78 90010054 3c60f658
3863240c 8124003c 80840030 81290048 <80a90000> 48001efd 813f003c 3c80f658
---[ end trace 4e540456ae707fcb ]---
2013 Dec  2 21:10:13 ATCA-8310-0-T0 last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/block/md0/dev
Segmentation fault
```

How can I debug this segmentation fault? How can I use the call trace to understand the issue?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151538/addr2line-on-kernel-module