# Debugging errors in device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver

this is the error log I am getting while doing insmod.I don't know why this error is coming because my driver program is compiled properly.Also if i try to rmmod i can't remove my module and it says my module is in use.

```
[25317.214214] Pid: 16780, comm: insmod Tainted: G           O 3.5.0-26-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu Dell Inc.                 OptiPlex GX620               /0HH807
[25317.214314] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa02fc020>]  [<ffffffffa02fc020>] bma220_init+0x20/0x1000 [test1]
[25317.214373] RSP: 0018:ffff880038c49f18  EFLAGS: 00010292
[25317.214409] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffa02f1100 RCX: ffffffff81e0cc00
[25317.214451] RDX: 00000000000076eb RSI: ffffffffa02f1020 RDI: 0000000000000246
[25317.214493] RBP: ffff880038c49f18 R08: 2074696e69206e69 R09: 000000000000062c
[25317.214539] R10: 303232616d622066 R11: 632e6c346d61735f R12: 0000000000000000
[25317.214583] R13: ffffffffa02fc000 R14: 00000000013aa010 R15: 0000000000000003
[25317.214626] FS:  00007fecd2ae1700(0000) GS:ffff88007f480000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[25317.214673] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[25317.214716] CR2: 0000000000000088 CR3: 00000000363c1000 CR4: 00000000000007e0
[25317.214758] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[25317.214800] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[25317.214842] Process insmod (pid: 16780, threadinfo ffff880038c48000, task ffff880015040000)
[25317.214889] Stack:
[25317.214902]  ffff880038c49f48 ffffffff8100203f ffffffffa02f1100 ffffffffffffffff
[25317.214952]  0000000000002984 00000000013aa010 ffff880038c49f78 ffffffff810b841e
[25317.215002]  00007fff2946095b 00000000013aa010 0000000000002984 0000000000004000
[25317.215051] Call Trace:
[25317.215074]  [<ffffffff8100203f>] do_one_initcall+0x3f/0x170
[25317.215113]  [<ffffffff810b841e>] sys_init_module+0xbe/0x220
[25317.215152]  [<ffffffff816a4269>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[25317.215189] Code: <48> 8b b8 88 00 00 00 48 83 c7 20 e8 80 fa ef e0 48 8b 05 29 53 ff 
[25317.215303] RIP  [<ffffffffa02fc020>] bma220_init+0x20/0x1000 [test1]
[25317.215345]  RSP <ffff880038c49f18>
[25317.215367] CR2: 0000000000000088
[25317.236534] ---[ end trace a7894e3fe062ad23 ]---
```

Comment: Looks like the init function of your module (`bma20_init`) has crashed. Before that crash message in the log, there should be a line or two describing the problem. Looks like the faulting instruction is MOV, so I would guess, it is some kind of incorrect memory access at the very beginning of initialization. Besides, [**addr2line**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151538/addr2line-on-kernel-module) tool may help find the source lines corresponding to `bma220_init+0x20` if the module is built with debug info.

Comment: I was doing sysfs_create_group as soon as i enter inside init function. I put that in the end i.e. after driver and device registration and this problem get solved.