# addr2line on kernel address cannot find source line

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb, addr2line

I am building a custom linux kernel (4.15.0 x86_64) with debug symbol enabled. I find that addr2line fails to point to the source code line.

> addr2line -e vmlinux 0xffffffff9be625f0

gdb also returns "No line number information available for address" with following command

> $ gdb ../linux/vmlinux /proc/kcore
>
> ... Reading symbols from ../linux/vmlinux...done.
>
> $ info line *0xffffffff9be625f0

What should be done to get the line number from address? Here is the [.config](https://gist.github.com/proywm/966ebf6a538cb1625b2a54ff0c9a26d5) file.

Comment: Are you sure that the address is inside vmlinux image? What if it is from some kernel module? (https://plus.google.com/+TheodoreTso/posts/h8H9z4EopkS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151538/addr2line-on-kernel-module/6153751)

Comment: @osgx, It's an address of a kernel symbol, not from kernel module. Got it from /proc/kallsym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - try to find out which procedure this address belongs to from /proc/kallsyms. Then compute the offset of this address from the beginning of this proc. Then:

```
objdump -D -S -l ./vmlinux | less
```

find your procedure name and then move to your offset.
Of course your kernel vmlinux should be compiled with debugging symbols.

Comment: I can understand that I can find the machine code using this method. But that was not my purpose. I wanted to find the line of the c file, which is the purpose of addr2line.

Comment: And with my method you'll find it - I always use this method. Second thing - I checked it on my embedded system, and symbols from modules are also listed int /proc/kallsyms, so maybe this address is from module, not from kernel itself, and that is the reason that addr2line is not showing the address?

Comment: Due to KASLR, addr2line fails to attribute. Disabling RANDOMIZE_BASE solved the problem.